# terminal with keybindings

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

I had been using Fedora 12 ( :-) ) until recently and moved to ubuntu. 
I used a lot of keybindings in "konsole" terminal for keyboard shortcuts.

I am not able to get any such terminal application on ubuntu. Even konsole too does not have keybindings working now

How do I get this working now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using autokey  https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/autokey-gtk/  on ubuntu. 
This solves the use case